# Spring Controller ModelAndView test MockMvc empty Response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I have this simple example setup to unit test spring Controller ModelAndView with MockMvc, but the response is always empty, even though in debug I can see that the controller code is executed.

Here's the code:

**/src/main/java/controller/MvcController.java**

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MvcController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{id}")
    public ModelAndView hello(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("hello", model);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="e"
    uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>HELLO WORLD
    </body>
</html>
```

**/src/test/java/controller/MvcControllerTest.java**

```
package controller;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MvcController.class })
public class MvcControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MvcController mvcController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mvcController).setViewResolvers(resolver).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello/XWQHEDg9e72t");
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        MvcResult mvcResult = result.andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse = mvcResult.getResponse();
        String response = mockHttpServletResponse.getContentAsString();
        assertThat(response).contains("HELLO WORLD");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word in `MockMvc` is *mock*. This framework does not set up a full Servlet container with a JSP engine. As such, it doesn't render the view that your controller returns and the `MockHttpServletResponse` does not contain a body (for this use case).

You can use [`MockHttpServletResponse#getForwardedUrl()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html#getForwardedUrl--) to get the url of the JSP that the Servlet container would've forwarded the request to, constructed from your view name and the prefix and suffix of your `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Comment: No way to render the view in the unit test?

Comment: Not with a JSP based view and MockMvc.